# How can we call Database Connectionstring from a async function while calling an api

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise, azure-keyvault

`//Dbconnect.js File

```
async function connect() {
  const credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
  const keyVaultName = "dbconnection";
  const url = "https://" + keyVaultName + ".vault.azure.net";
  const client = new SecretClient(url, credential);

  const connection = await mysql.createConnection({
    host: (await client.getSecret('host')).value,
    user: (await client.getSecret('user')).value,
    password: '',
    database:(await client.getSecret('database')).value,
  });
  connection.connect((err) => {
        if(err){
          console.log('Error connecting to Db');
          return;
        }
        console.log('Connection established successfully');
      });
    return connection;
}
connect().catch((error) => {
  console.error("An error occurred:", error);
  process.exit(1);
});

module.exports.connect = connect;

//APi.js File
const mysql = require('../DbConnect').connect;
exports.customerInformation = async (req, res) => {
    let qry = "select * from customerinformation"; 
    mysql query(qry, (err, results) => {
    if (err){
    res.status(500).json({response:"500",status:'Failed',message:"Internal Server Error"});
    }
    else {
            if (results.length > 0) {
                 res.status(200).json({response:"200",status:'success',data:results});
            }else{
                 res.status(404).json({response:"404",status:'Failed',message:"Invalid Credential"});
            }
         }
    })
};
```

`

Keyvault secrets are fectched and Connection Is getting established successfully. But when I am Trying to call the  API It is SHowing query is not defined as the error

Comment: you aren't waiting for `connection.connect` to complete inside your `connect` function - also `mysql query(qry, (err, results) => {` is invalid syntax is it not?

Comment: It is showing as the Connection Established Successfully . From Connect function but while calling the api it is showing query is not defined as it could not search for the database connection string from the connect function

Comment: sure it is - but that doesn't mean the query is waiting for that .. .and anyway, `mysql query(qry, (err, results)` looks wrong .... still ...should that be `mysql.query(qry, (err, results)` - since `query` would be undefined since you don't define it anywhere, but `mysql.query` is likely to be making a query using the mysql connection you just required